# Isolating a VM from the local network but allowing internet - what are my options?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-network

I want to set up a development environment locally with a *virtual network* where:

1. My VM is blocked from accessing the local network ranges (192.168.0.0/16, and a few other ranges via VPN).
2. My VM has access to the internet through the host gateway (192.168.1.1) via Wi-Fi.
3. My host can initiate connections to my VM (e.g. ssh).

I am having a hard time in finding what my options are for accomplishing this configuration, so I wanted to ask for a good solution to this.

My host PC is Windows 10 Pro, and I run VirtualBox with a linux VM. I am not sure if it matters but I have a wireless network card (Intel Wireless-AC 9560) and a physical NIC card (Intel Ethernet I219-LM) where the cable is disconnected.

My search for a solution online didn't really come up with any good solutions with clear instructions on how to create a firewall and restrict the VM network access. Here are the things I found, but I fear I don't have time to go into all of these.

- The unofficial way to achieve my desired setup with virtualbox is to use a "Sandbox" mode where an additional VM runs [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) that acts as a bridge/router and firewall. Here is the [description of the "Sandbox" network topology](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=96608#p468780). My issue with this topology is that it uses a full VM instance (1+ CPUs and 2GB+ of RAM) just for the purpose of running a firewall.
- I saw some hints that it might be possible to create a bridge between physical network interface cards and give the VM access to one of them, but when I tried bridging my unused NIC to the Wi-Fi I just lost internet, so I 'm not sure how to achieve anything going that way.
- I found a software called [Open vSwitch](https://www.openvswitch.org/) but it seems I might need to build it from source. And it is a bit unclear for me how well it will work with Windows 10.
- I am thinking it could maybe be possible to use the Windows Firewall, to block VM attempts at communication on my local network. Am I right or does a VM dip into network resources at a lower level than the Windows Firewall? Perhaps it depends on the network configuration of the VM as well. I saw a thread where someone claimed to have achieve a working setup this way, but they had to set up firewall rules for "all the applications" so it's still a bit unclear to me what I need to do to make that work.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest a more lightweight solution than the "Sandbox", and give some hints for how to set it up too? Even short tips could also be extremely helpful to me, as my lack of knowledge with virtual networking makes it difficult to find a good solution by search.

Comment: Try Host Only and then use USB pass through for a USB network card for the Guest to get Internet.

Comment: Firewall is the way to do it. On Linux you filter with the "forward" chain/hook of ip/nftables. Not sure if the Windows firewall have this sort of infrastructure for you though, since even enabling IP forwarding on Windows requires you to edit registry. Having a NIC on the host bridged and/or a dedicated NIC for it isn't really relevant, unless your home router supports VLAN or so, or your ISP allows you to get more than one public / CGNAT IP (i.e. the dedicated NIC won't be connected to your home router but whatever that practically gives you an extra "wall port").